# iPhone/iPad says 'Download Failed' when trying to load website

Tags: iphone, ios, codeigniter, web

I have a weird issue. Whenever I do something like login it will create the session, but then say 'Download Failed Safari cannot download this file' and doesn't redirect. If I go the the actual page that it should have redirected me to I am logged in. The same things happens any time you do anything such as logout, upload content, etc.

It only happens on iOS devices in Safari on 3G. Wifi it works just fine. Chrome on the iPhone works fine on 3G. Obviously its like its trying to download something, but I can't seem to figure out why this is, or why it is.

It happens when I am login in to my profile, but if that profile is public and I just go directly to that page without logging in there is not issue. Make sense?.....

The site is built in Codeigniter. If any one has ANY sort of idea that would be great!!!

Comment: If the phone is saying "download failed", then the page is being served up as something that the phone doesn't see as a webpage (bad headers? bad mime type?) and tries to download it instead, as any browser would when it encounters something unknown.

Comment: The odd things is that I don't have the issue on the test site that is on a different server, but same code. The test server is a dedicated server and the live site is on a amazon aws server.

Comment: then look at what the server differences are.  just because it's the same code in both places doesn't mean it'll be executed the same way.

Comment: Try setting `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;` in `application/config/config.php`. If that fixes it, then something is wrong with your gzip output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with a server configuration that was causing the issue. Even thought I had $config['compress_output'] = FALSE; set it was still utilizing gzip. We turned it off in the server configuration and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your device to use a proxy such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com).  Look for the differences between a successful request/response and a failed request/response.